# why ADF Default data type for date column is "oracle.jbo.domain.date"

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-adf

whenever i create the entities using wizards in   ADF J developer 11.1.2.3 , the default Data type for Date column in Database table is always is

- Oracle.jbo.domain.date
- Oracle.jbo.domain.TimeStamp

any idea ???

Comment: Had I is you actual question? You are right, ADF uses oracle.jbo.domain.Date have class for db dates.

Comment: yes @TimoHahn  , why ADF does not takes db dates as java.uil.date ??